# C++ references - are they just syntactic sugar?

Tags: c++

Is a C++ reference just syntactic sugar, or does it offer any speed ups in certain cases?

For example, a call-by-pointer involves a copy anyway, and that seems to be true about a call-by-reference as well. The underlying mechanism appears to be the same.

Edit: After about six answers and many comments. I am still of the opinion references are just syntatic sugar. If people could answer in a straight yes or no, and if someone could do an accepted answer?

Comment: Please cite evidence of your statement: `a call-by-pointer involves a copy anyway, and that seems to be true about a call-by-reference as well. The underlying mechanism appears to be the same`

Comment: References are just references, from the language standpoint. Trying to concentrate on an implementation detail (although very prevalent) - pointers - will only lead to an error of judgement due to [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias): if X is similar to Y then thinking most properties that apply to X will also apply to Y, AND you'll be wrong in assuming so. So maintain, in your mental model, those two as separate entities because they're.

Comment: References are different to pointers *semantically*. So, no, they're not just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @juanchopanza Exactly! Them getting implemented in a fashion similar to pointers should mean nothing for the language user.

Comment: *call-by-pointer involves a copy anyway, and that seems to be true about a call-by-reference as well* Yes. Weren't that the case, it should be called call-by-telepathy (or `__fastcall`)

Comment: Note that according to [Stroustrup's HOPL paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf) (see Section 3.3.4), the big motivation for introducing references into the language was indeed a purely syntactical one: To allow operator overloading as we have it in the language today. This would simply have been very awkward to do with just pointers (this is explained in greater detail in _Design and Evolution of C++_). Since then the language has of course evolved a lot, so by now there are lots of other reasons to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @EdChum I just read a few confident comments\answers on so

Comment: @EdChum a call-by-pointer requires a copy of the pointer itself, as all function calls require copies of the passed in values. I think he means references are just fancy ways of supplying a pointer to the object in a way where the pointer itself is abstracted, but still there in the compiled implementation (but with different optimised characteristics)

Comment: My preferred term is "syntactic vinegar", since they vastly uglify/sour the code by obscuring whether the callee has access to the caller's object or just to a value.

Comment: There is much more to language features than syntax and optimisation opportunities. -1

Comment: @ComicSansMS Introducing a new syntax in order to support a new feature is pretty much the opposite of syntactic sugar, where the two syntaxes are functionally identical

Comment: @Izkata But in case of operator overloading they _are_ functionally identical. The only reasons it was not feasible with pointers alone was that it looked ugly with all the explicit `&`s (_notational convenience_ is the term that Stroustrup uses in D&E) and clashed with existing C syntax. In the end, the only thing that separates operator overloading from plain function calls is the syntax sugar.

Answer (score 66):

Assume reference as a pointer that:

1. Can't be NULL
2. Once initialized, can't be re-pointed to other object
3. Any attempt to use it will implicitly dereference it:

   ```
   int a = 5;
   int &ra = a;
   int *pa = &a;

   ra = 6;

   (*pa) = 6;
   ```

here as it looks in disassembly:

```
    int a = 5;
00ED534E  mov         dword ptr [a],5  
    int &ra = a;
00ED5355  lea         eax,[a]  
00ED5358  mov         dword ptr [ra],eax  
    int *pa = &a;
00ED535B  lea         eax,[a]  
00ED535E  mov         dword ptr [pa],eax  

    ra = 6;
00ED5361  mov         eax,dword ptr [ra]  
00ED5364  mov         dword ptr [eax],6  

    (*pa) = 6;
00ED536A  mov         eax,dword ptr [pa]  
00ED536D  mov         dword ptr [eax],6
```

the assigning to the reference is the same thing from the compiler perspective as the assigning to a dereferenced pointer. There are no difference between them as you can see (we are not talking about compiler optimization right now)
However as mentioned above, references can't be null and have stronger guarantees of what they contains.

As for me, I prefer using references as long as I don't need `nullptr` as a valid value, values that should be repointed or values of different types to be passed into (e.g. pointer to interface type).

Comment: You actually answered the user's question without adding anything like "don't even think about it like that" or "please give evidence to support your question" or using the term "X Y problem".  SO may not congratulate you on that, but I will.

Comment: @user1903064: Then may I be the first to congratulate you for being one against 4.4million users. Their opinion, of course, pales in comparison to yours, oh great one! :)

Comment: You gave code with optimizations turned off.  Comparing what code does without optimizations on is relatively pointless.

Comment: Off course optimization was off. That allows us to see high level syntax on low level implementation. What do you wan't to see with optimization on? This particular example will not be compiled at all. It will be skipped during optimization process as useless. One example of optimized code will show us almost nothing. Well, it will show us that in some case one approach is better than the other but there will still be thousands cases not tested yet.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Make that two.

Comment: @VinSmile Well, the whole point is that references cannot be reduced to syntactic sugar only when you consider optimizations. From the language point of view with pointers you can express the same (a superset) semantics as with references. Thus, optimizations are very important point which make a practical difference. Moreover, there are many reverse cases, where c++ idioms could be called slower than c due to highlevel "overhead", however when you turn in optimization they get more than often reduced to the effective implementations. c++ is designed around possible optimizations.

Comment: @luk32, You are absolutely right. I just mentioned that it's hard to predict what will lead to better optimization in each particular case (unless you know all compiler optimization strategies :) ). Anyway compilers do make good optimization and often there is no need to help them doing it. Unless you write some embedded application that requires huge performance/size optimization (really rare case, and guys who write them can give us much more details of things under the hood). in 99% if you want to optimize code doing it less readable or less safe, you better think twice.

Answer (score 59):

References have stronger guarantees than pointers, so the compiler can optimize more aggressively. I've recently seen GCC inline multiple nested calls through function references perfectly, but not a single one through function pointers (because it couldn't prove that the pointer was always pointing at the same function).

If the reference ends up stored somewhere, it typically takes the same space as a pointer. That is not to say, again, that it will be used like a pointer : the compiler may well cut through it if it knows which object the reference was bound to.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve everything that could be achieved with a reference, with a pointer?

Comment: @samofoz No. Language-wise: you cannot take the address of a temporary, but you can bind a reference to a temporary. Optimisation-wise: a reference is guaranteed to refer to a valid object, a pointer can always be null.

Comment: @samofoz No, nor the other way around. For example, a reference can extend the lifetime of a temporary, but a pointer can be assigned.

Comment: @Angew: *a reference is guaranteed to refer to a valid object, a pointer can always be null* Could you quote the standard on that one? It seems that you can dereference a null pointer and get a reference to no object. Is this UB?

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Dereferencing an invalid pointer, or the null pointer, is UB.

Comment: @user23013 Edit: scratch that, I answered too fast. The pointer wasn't declared `const`, but it was a template parameter, so a pretty good constant indeed.

Comment: Aside from some useless formalism, there is no difference in the UB of dereferencing (but not actually loading/storing) a null pointer to obtain a reference that will be used for loads/stores later, versus performing loads/stores via a direct dereference. References **do not** have any "stronger guarantees", in terms of actual safety, than pointers. They just shuffle the formal point of UB around.

Comment: @Quentin: If the compiler couldn't optimize with a pointer but could optimize with a reference, the compiler probably failed to prove non-aliasing with the pointer version. There are various ways to address that problem.

Comment: Your anecdote seems weird, where is the code? It seems that GCC could optimize as well if the pointer was **const** (preventing re-seating).

Comment: @Angew you can easily have a dangling reference.

Answer (score 20):

The compiler cannot assume a pointer is non-null; when optimizing code, it has to either prove the pointer is non-null, or emit a program that accounts for the possibility that it is null (in a context where that would be well-defined).

Similarly, the compiler cannot assume the pointer never changes value. (nor can it assume the pointer points to a valid object, although I'm having trouble imagining a case where that would matter in a well-defined context)

On the other hand, assuming that references are implemented as pointers, the compiler *is* still allowed to assume it is non-null, never changes where it points, and points to a valid object.

Comment: Not sure I can agree with the first point. The thing is that as soon as the pointer is dereferenced, the compiler is free to apply all those optimizations as well. If the pointer was indeed NULL or invalid, the dereferencing already sent you to undefined-behavior-land, so any optimizations are valid. So the only situations where this applies is when you have pointer-code that _could_ be optimized if you knew that the pointer was valid, but never dereferences said pointer (so the UB argument does not apply). And I have the feeling that this is a rather uncommon scenario.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: Not all uses of pointers are to dereference; my first thought was actually taking the address of the reference and passing it into some other (inlined) function that takes a pointer as an argument that has to do a check for being a null pointer.

Comment: But wouldn't this check be done by your code instead of the compiler? I agree that, as a developer, you are much more likely to produce code where it's harder to optimize for the compiler. But if my only goal as a developer was to write pointer-code that can be just as well optimized as reference-code, shouldn't I be able to do so? Unfortunately, I'm not really a compiler guy, but assuming that the UB argument from my earlier comment holds, this seems very well possible to me. Granted, this is all getting a bit theoretical now, so apologies for that.

Comment: Note that the second point is the same as const pointers, eg `int*const`.

Comment: @celticminstrel: Not always so! `const` doesn't mean "this value can't change": it means "you can't change this value using this variable". There are times when you can prove it can't change (without UB), but you'd have to know the standard in pretty fine detail to do so by hand.

Comment: @Hurkyl if the pointer itself is declared const, it is a true constant. You're talking about a pointer to a const object : read-only, not necessarily constant.

Comment: @Quentin: Actually, the examples I have in mind are all of the form reference-to-pointer-constant, or similar.

Comment: @Quentin: ... but those are only the cases I know about. Sure if I have a local variable that is a pointer constant that is never passed by reference to anything I can be sure it is truly a constant. But what if I do pass it by reference to something? Or if I use an `extern int *const`? This is not something I've seen taught, and I certainly don't have a deep enough knowledge of the standard to know of I can arrange that such things can change -- or even if I can't do it portably, if a library or an implementation is allowed to change them.

Comment: @Hurkyl When you declare a const reference to an object, you have already declared said object somewhere, and thus sealed its constness there. About the `extern`, declaring an extern name twice with different types is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Quentin: `int *p; int *const &q = p;` Despite `q` being a reference to a pointer constant, it's value will change if I modify `p` (and also, modifying it through `const_cast<int *&>(q)` would be legal). This could arise naturally, for example, if you had a vector of pointers, and obtained a reference to an element through a const iterator. This is also a naturally occurring source of errors, e.g. when a function receives two references, and mistakenly assumes modifying one can't change the other. Or receives a reference to something that gets modified by a function call used by the function.

Comment: @Hurkyl `p` has *not* been declared const in your example.

Answer (score 11):

**No**

---

References are not just a *syntactic* difference; they also have different *semantics*:

- A reference always aliases an existing object, unlike a pointer which may be `nullptr` (a sentinel value).
- A reference cannot be re-seated, it always points to the same object throughout its lifetime.
- A reference can extend the lifetime of an object, see binding to `auto const&` or `auto&&`.

Thus, at the language level, a reference is an entity of its own. The rest are implementation details.

Comment: The first point is not exact. Functions returning a pointer are common in C and C++ so that the scenario where a function taking a reference argument is called with a dereferenced pointer is common, and that pointer might well be NULL. You miss an important difference between pointers and references: references cannot be deleted.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald: References cannot be null, it is undefined behavior to dereference a null pointer and therefore undefined behavior to form a "null-reference". Discussing what could happen in a program exhibiting undefined behavior is pointless (from the language point of view) as by definition any behavior is correct. As for cannot be deleted... well, in modern C++ calling `delete` manually is a red herring anyway so I don't find it a very important difference.

Answer (score 10):

References differ from pointers in that there are things you cannot do to a reference and have it be defined behavior.

You cannot take the address of a reference, but only what is referred to.  You cannot modify a reference once it is created.

A `T&` and a `T*const` (note that `const` applies to the pointer, not the pointed-to, there) are relatively similar.  Taking the address of an actual `const` value and modifying it is undefined behavior, as is modifying (any storage that it uses directly) a reference.

Now, in practice, you can get a the storage of a reference:

```
struct foo {
  int& x;
};
```

`sizeof(foo)` will almost certainly equal `sizeof(int*)`.  But the compiler is free to neglect the possibility that someone directly accessing the bytes of `foo` could actually change the value referred to.  This permits the compiler to read the reference "pointer" implementation once, and then never read it again.  If we had `struct foo{ int* x; }` the compiler would have to prove each time it did a `*f.x` that the pointer value had not changed.

If you had `struct foo{ int*const x; }` is again starts behaving reference-like in its immutability (modifying something that was declared `const` is UB).

---

A trick that I'm not aware of any compiler writers using is to compress reference-capture in a lambda.

If you have a lambda that captures data by reference, instead of capturing each value via a pointer, it could capture only the stack frame pointer.  The offsets to each local variable are compile-time constants off the stack frame pointer.

The exception is references captured by reference, which under a defect report to C++ must remain valid even if the reference variable goes out of scope.  So those have to be captured by pseudo-pointer.

For a concrete example (if a toy one):

```
void part( std::vector<int>& v, int left, int right ) {
  std::function<bool(int)> op = [&](int y){return y<left && y>right;};
  std::partition( begin(v), end(v), op );
}
```

the lambda above could capture only the stack frame pointer, and know where `left` and `right` are relative to it, reducing it size, instead of capturing two `int`s by (basically pointer) reference.

Here we have references implied by `[&]` whose existence is eliminated easier than if they where pointers captured by value:

```
void part( std::vector<int>& v, int left, int right ) {
  int* pleft=&left;
  int* pright=&right;
  std::function<bool(int)> op = [=](int y){return y<*pleft && y>*pright;};
  std::partition( begin(v), end(v), op );
}
```

---

There are a few other differences between references and pointers.

A reference can extend the lifetime of a temporary.

This is used heavily in `for(:)` loops.  Both the definition of the `for(:)` loop relies on reference lifetime extension to avoid needless copies, and users of `for(:)` loops can use `auto&&` to automatically deduce the lightest weight way to wrap the iterated objects.

```
struct big { int data[1<<10]; };

std::array<big, 100> arr;

arr get_arr();

for (auto&& b : get_arr()) {
}
```

here reference lifetime extension carefully prevents needless copies from ever occuring.  If we change `make_arr` to return a `arr const&` it continues to work without any copies.  If we change `get_arr` to return a container that returns `big` elements by-value (say, an input iterator range), again no needless copies are done.

This is in a sense syntactic sugar, but it allows the same construct to be optimal in many cases without having to micro-optimize based on how things are returned or iterated over.

---

Similarly, forwarding references allow data to be treated as a const, non-const, lvalue or rvalue intelligently.  Temporaries are marked as temporaries, data that users have no further need for is marked as temporary, data that will persist is marked as being an lvalue reference.

The advantage references have over non-references here is that you can form a rvalue reference to a temporary, and you cannot form a pointer to that temporary without passing it through an rvalue reference-to-lvalue reference conversion.

Answer (score 9):

There used to be efficiency advantages because references are easier for the compiler to optimize.  However, modern compilers have gotten so good at it that there is no longer any advantage.

One **huge** advantage references have over pointers is that a reference can refer to a value in a register, while pointers can only point at blocks of memory.  Take the address of something which would have been in a register, and you would force the compiler to put that value into a normal memory location instead.  This can create tremendous benefits in tight loops.

However, modern compilers are so good that they now recognize a pointer that *could have been* a reference for all intents and purposes, and treat it exactly the same as if it were a reference.  This can cause rather intriguing results in a debugger, where you can have a statement such as `int* p = &x`, ask the debugger to print the value of `p`, only to have it say something along the lines of "p cannot be printed" because `x` was actually in a register, and the compiler was treating `*p` as a reference to `x`!  In this case, there literally is no value for `p`

(However, if you tried to do pointer arithmetic on `p`, you would then force the compiler to no longer optimize the pointer to act like a reference does, and everything would slow down)

Answer (score 1):

**8.3.2 References [dcl.ref]**

> A reference can be thought of as a name of an object

which is different from **pointers** which is a variable (unlike reference) that holds the address of a memory location of an Object<sup>**</sup>. The type of this variable is pointer to Object.

Internally Reference may be implemented as pointer, but standard never guaranteed so.

So to answer your question: C++Reference are not syntactic sugar to pointers. And whether it provides any speedup has already been answered in depth.

<sup>****** Object here it means any instance that has a memory address. Even pointers are Objects and so are functions (and thus we have nested pointers and function pointers). In similar sense, we do not have pointers to reference as they are not instantiated.</sup>

Comment: The standard also doesn't guarantee pointers are implemented so to store memory addresses. Even if solely because of the as-if rule.